# How to use touches began?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mobile, uiview

So I'm writing an app in which I have a custom UIView which contains a UIScrollView which contains a series of UIImageViews. I want to make it so that when I touch one of the UIImageViews within the UIScrollView, an event happens (for now, let's just say I print an NSLog() or something).

I know that there exists this function:

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to use it. Which UIView should implement this function? Where would I call it exactly? Or does it get called automatically when something is touched? How do I find the correct UIImageView?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image views. Keep in mind that you need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for a `UIImageView` to handle touch events.

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is already implemented by UIView (actually implemented by the UIResponder superclass, and by default it does nothing). this method is there for you to override in subclasses to do whatever you want to do.

this method is indeed called automatically whenever touches begin within the views boundary.

In your case using a UIButton with an image may be better.

Comment: So then I should create a custom UIImageView class and then implement touchesBegan within that class? Would I have to do any sort of bounds checking or is that handled for me?

Comment: you wont receive the message if the touch is outside the view bounds (it will go to some other view instead). Sounds like you maybe want to subclass UIImageView.

Comment: @user1855952 you may actually want to use a UIButton, its not exactly clear what your requirements are.

Comment: I could use a UIButton I suppose but UIButtons have more overhead and for efficiency reasons I wanted to avoid using them.

Comment: @user1855952 what makes you say that UIButton would perform worse? Don't try to prematurely optimize something so trivial.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `touchesBegin:` , subclass UIImageView, add Tap gesture to this new Class and use this Class instead of the ImageViews you are using on scrollView.